# How can I programmatically join an EC2 instance to a domain / Active Directory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, active-directory

I searched around, didn't see an api / reference doc talking about the flow for joining an EC2 instance to an existing domain / Active Directory on creating the instance. Is that all possible?

Answer (score 1):

AWS posted a blog with full details and example:

- [How to Configure Your EC2 Instances to Automatically Join a Microsoft Active Directory Domain](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-configure-your-ec2-instances-to-automatically-join-a-microsoft-active-directory-domain/)
- [Managing domain membership of dynamic fleet of EC2 instances](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-configure-your-ec2-instances-to-automatically-join-a-microsoft-active-directory-domain/)